# GTK# window resizable

Tags: c#, monodevelop, gtk#

how to make a window size fix in GTK#??
let w be a window class, i try to use Resizable bool variable,but it failed.

```
Window w = new Window("");
w.Resizable = false;
```

Anyone can help??

Answer (score 1):

See if you can get this one to work instead.

Set FormBorderStyle to FixedDialog

Answer (score 0):

In GTK#:

w.AllowGrow = false;
w.AllowShrink = false;